# ActionController::RoutingError No route matches [GET] "/stories"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

OS: openSUSE 11.4 
Rails 3.2.0

I just created a very simple application "koko". Here are the order of commands I ran

```
rails new koko
rails generate model Story name:string description:string
rake db:migrate
rails generate controller Stories index
```

All above commands executed successfully. 
I then ran =>rails server to start the server. 
localhost:3000/ works fine.

When i try to do 
localhost:3000/stores I get the following error: (the browser displayes the first line about No route matches)

```
Started GET "/stories" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Aug 04 12:52:02 -0400 2012
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stories"):
  actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
  railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:104:in `service'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/httpserver.rb:65:in `run'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:173:in `start_thread'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start_thread'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:95:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `each'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:92:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:23:in `start'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/webrick/server.rb:82:in `start'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:13:in `run'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/server.rb:265:in `start'
  railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
  railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:55
  railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
  railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/commands.rb:50
  script/rails:6:in `require'
  script/rails:6


Rendered /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.9ms)
```

Comment: Here is the route file :

Koso::Application.routes.draw do
  get "stories/index"
end

Comment: Try changing your routing file to have __resources :stories__ instead of __get "stories/index__

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are trying to use a RESTful interface to a non-RESTful resource. You made a model, and you made a controller with an index action, (`/controller_name/action`).

If you are happy with using `/stories/index`, then we're done! If you prefer the more traditional RESTful interface `/stories`, then I would suggest using:

`rails generate resource ModelName fields:types`.

This will create a Model and a Controller, and should work restfully out of the box. This will set up the route that was mentioned in the comments.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You might simply have some naming problems. Generally, when creating a controller it should be

```
rails g controller stories index
```

or

```
rails g controller Story index
```

Then change your automatically-generated route to

```
match "/stories" => "stories#index", :as => "stories"
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes that was it, a simple mismatch between the  Modelname and the ControllerName. One was Story while the other was Stories. Thank you again!!

Comment: Actually i didnt have to change the route